# React Native call android java class's Constructor

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Sorry for my English. I want to call android java class's constructor in react native's js. I don't know what to do. I follow the [guides](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html). When I call new myclass() in js, react native jump up an error "TypeError: _ myclass2.default is not a constructor". Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've to export and import classes accordingly.

**Use to export:**

```
export default class MyClass2...
```

**Use to import**

```
import MyClass2 from '...';
```

**Alternatively if you have to export multiple classes use:**

```
export class MyClass1...
export class MyClass2...

import { MyClass1, MyClass2 } from '...';
```

Always write classes starting with uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I ask is how to call constructor in a java class from react native's js files. I exported the java class with `import {
    NativeModules
} from 'react-native';

module.exports = NativeModules.Myclass;
`. But when I call the constructor, it jump out an error `TypeError: _ myclass2.default is not a constructor`

Comment: how do you declare the constructor, which type of constructor do you use?